# What are the differences between 'will' and 'would'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

1. Every single day when I sit to write something, I am to think what I *will* write.
2. Every single day when I sit to write something, I am to think what I *would* write.

Please say what are the differences between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions themselves are not grammatically correct, and the *I am to think* bit is rather confusing, but I get your *meaning*, so I am going to focus purely on **will** and **would**.

```
I think to myself: what will I write?
```

*Will* has many meanings, with the words placed around it filling in the gaps. In the above sense, the implication is that ***something is going to be written*** one way or the other. It really does not matter *what* is written, only that the act of the writing is done.

```
I think to myself: what would I write?
```

*Would* can easily make the above hypothetical. *If*, every single day, I sat down to write something, I think to myself, what *would* I write? Here, the *I think to myself* is practically parenthetic:

```
If, every single day, I sat down to write something (I think to myself),
what would I write?
```

In this sense, *will* speaks to actually getting some writing done, whereas *would* implies **thinking about it without actually starting**.

Will = action.
Would = thought.

This is not a pure definition of either word, in and of themselves - it is how they fit in the puzzle that is your question.