# Learning the usage of present participle

Tags: present-participles, participles

I'd appreciate it if anybody helped me to learn the following topic.

- In this case, *will* speaks to actually **getting** some writing done, whereas *would* implies **thinking** about it without actually **starting**.

This sentence has been recited from [this link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74177/what-are-the-differences-between-will-and-would/74178#74178)

I easily understand the meaning of this sentence. But I want to learn the usage of present participles indicated in bold words. Please instruct me the rules how they have been used in this sentence, so that I will be able to use present participles in the same way they have been used in the above stated sentence.

Comment: You may find the tag-wiki on [*verb-forms*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-forms/info) a useful quick introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 4):

The *-ing* form of the verb has three broad uses:

- As a component of the **progressive construction** following a form of the verb *BE*. This typically expresses *imperfective* or *progressive* aspect (action which occurs continuously or repeatedly), or to ‘recategorize’ a  stative verb as a temporary activity:

  > We **are building** a house in Chesterfield.
  >   When I saw him he **was running** to catch the bus.
  >   I**’m feeling** pretty good about the current state of the project.
  >   George **is being** a jerk.
- As an adjective to express performance of an action at reference time; in this use it is traditionally called a **present participle**<sup>†</sup>:

  > The **running** child tripped and fell.

  When the participle takes verbal arguments such as objects or complements, or is modified by a following adverbial, the participle phrase is placed **after** the noun it modifies:

  > The child **running** across the playground tripped and fell.
- As a noun expressing the action, fact or state of the verb; in this use it is traditionally called a **gerund**.<sup>†</sup>:

  > I enjoy **playing** golf, but **swimming** is my favorite pastime.
  >   You will succeed by **working** hard.

  The uses you offer are all such gerunds:

  > to actually **getting** some writing done ... *The gerund acts like a noun as object of the preposition* to, *and like a verb in supporting the adverb modifier* actually *and in taking the Direct Object,* writing.
  >
  > getting some **writing** done ... *The gerund exhibits no verbal properties, and acts like a noun in taking a determiner,* some, *and in taking an adjectival past participle*, done, *as a modifier.*
  >
  > *would* implies **thinking** about it ... *The gerund acts like a noun in acting as the Direct Object of the verb* implies *and like a verb in taking the complement preposition phrase* about it.
  >
  > without actually **starting** ... *The gerund acts like a noun as object of the preposition* without *and like a verb in supporting the adverb modifier* actually.

---

<sup>†</sup> The traditional terminology is controversial—is the *-ing* form one form or two? Historically, it’s two different forms which have collapsed into one; the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls it a *gerund-participle*. And there’s a good deal of heat around whether the *-ing* form ever actually operates as a noun or should not rather be regarded as a verb heading a clause which acts as a noun; see for instance the Answers and Comments [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292397/what-part-of-speech-is-talking-in-the-following-sentence) on ELU.